# Convert a python list of python lists to pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

What is the conventional way to convert python list of lists to PyTorch tensors?

```
a = [0,0]
b = [1,1]
c = [2]
c = [a, b, c]
```

I want c to be converted to a flattened Torch tensor as below:

```
torch([ 0, 0, 1, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten your list first in Python:

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in c for item in sublist]
```

And create your Tensor:

```
flattened_tensor = torch.FloatTensor(flat_list)
```